# How to add contcat in Roster without sending and accepting subscription request in xmpp chatting

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

I have download yaxim source code from github [yaxim link](https://github.com/pfleidi/yaxim)
Now I want to implement adding contact in Roster without sending and accepting subscription request, i didn't find any documents that describes code and explain it with document, 
So I need a solution , I try with github code but I can't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own stanza if you want to just add user to your roster. The XML stanza would look like below. You can find info on 
http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#int.

I had a similar requirement on my project but I have been using JsJaC bosh library with openfire as XMPP server.

```
     <iq type='set' id='set1'>
        <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'>
         <item
           jid='contact@example.org'
           name='MyContact'>
           <group>MyBuddies</group>
         </item>
       </query>
     </iq>
```

Answer (score 0):

After so many research Finally I found that its not possible (or hardly possible if we do some change in library and in our own server) to add contact directly without sending and accepting subscription request, but I found that we can add contacts to end user side without User Interface asking to end user for accepting the subscription request and I have done it in my application.